# Raty Star rating in Google map infowindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow, raty

I have added marker on google map with some search results.

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var marker, i;
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var contentString="";var image_path1="";
    contentString += '<div class="browse-map-venue" style="padding:5px;width: 230px;">';
        contentString += '<div class="rating" style="float: right; padding-right: 10px;">';
            contentString += '<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>media/front/js/jquery.raty.min.js"><\/script>';
            contentString += '<script>';
            contentString += '$(function() {';
            contentString += '$("#rating_fixed_rate_pop_'+ i +'").raty({';
            contentString += 'readOnly: true,';
            contentString += 'half: true,';
            contentString += 'start: '+ locations[i][6] +',';
            contentString += 'score: '+ locations[i][6] +',';
            contentString += 'path: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>media/front/img"';
            contentString += '});';
            contentString += '});';
            contentString += '<\/script> ';
            contentString += '<div id="rating_fixed_rate_pop_'+ i +'"></div>';
            contentString += '<a href="javascript:void(0);">'+ locations[i][7] +' reviews</a>';
            contentString += '</div>';
    contentString += '</div>';
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1],locations[i][2]),
        title: locations[i][3],
        info: contentString,
        map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(this.info);
        infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
}
```

But I need to add star rating with raty js which not getting applied to it when I click on marker.

Note: When we edit script written for rating from console and just after pressing enter it shows the stars. But I need those to be displayed when I click on marker in infowindow only.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. what does the code the browser sees look like? 2. the infowindow won't be part of the DOM until the `domready` event fires.

Comment: all the above code is written in script after ajax call only. I just have written the required code for displaying marker with infowindow

Comment: php is a server side language, if that is appearing in the browser, it won't work.

Comment: In above code, I guess php is used only for path. And I am working on php and above code is in search results page, where I need to show data on google map with search results fetched. As per my assumption php will not affect on this functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Instead of using a string use a node to create the content(to be able to easily access the content via jQuery)
2. store the rating as a attribute of the particular node(to be able to use a single function to create the stars)

simple demo:

```js
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 5,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(2, 2),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          },
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            mapOptions),
          locations = [
            [null, 1, 1, 'title#1', null, null, 1.3, 'foo'],
            [null, 2, 2, 'title#2', null, null, 3.7, 'bar'],
            [null, 3, 3, 'title#3', null, null, 4.3, 'boofar']
          ],
          infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(),
          i;
        //use the domready-event of the infowindow to execute $.raty
        google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function() {
          $(this.getContent()).find('.stars').raty({
            half: true,
            score: function() {
              return $(this).attr('data-score');
            },
            readOnly: true,
            path: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wbotelhos/raty/master/demo/images/'
          });
        });
        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
          (function(location) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: new google.maps.LatLng(location[1], location[2]),
              title: location[3],
              map: map,
              info: $('<div/>')
                //the rating
                .append($('<div class="stars"></div>').attr('data-score', location[6]))
                //review-link
                .append($('<a href="javascript:void(0);">' + locations[i][7] + ' reviews</a>'))
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
              infowindow.setContent(this.info[0]);
              infowindow.open(map, this);
            });
          }(locations[i]))






        }
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wbotelhos/raty/master/lib/jquery.raty.js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```